# Typescript error removing an object from an array

Tags: angular, typescript

In a project in angular I have a table with several elements and in each row there is a button that is used to delete the corresponding row.
In the button I inserted an event that on click calls a function and passes the id of the object:

```
<button mat-flat-button (click)="removePhase(phase.id)">
   <span><mat-icon>close</mat-icon></span>
</button>
```

when pressed calls this function:

```
removePhase(id:number){
    console.log(this.phase) /*First log*/
    this.phase.forEach((element) => {
    if (element.id != id) {
      this.phaseRemove.push(element);
      }
    })
    this.phaseRemove.forEach((element, index) => {
      element.id = index;
    })
    this.phase = this.phaseRemove;
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.phase);
    console.log(this.phase) /*Second log*/
  }
```

this is the phase object:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "phaseName": "Phase 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "phaseName": "Phase 2"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "phaseName": "Phase 3"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "phaseName": "Phase 4"
    }
]
```

when the function is launched the first time everything works normally, while when I launch it a second time it loops the first for.
I entered two console logs to see what happens and in the first one I get this object (in this thing I pressed the button to delete the object with id 0):

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "phaseName": "Phase 1",
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "phaseName": "Phase 2",
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "phaseName": "Phase 3",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "phaseName": "Phase 4",
    }
]
```

and in the second log, I get the correct object instead:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "phaseName": "Phase 2",
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "phaseName": "Phase 3",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "phaseName": "Phase 4",
    }
]
```

As you can see the console log of the first object also sets the id 0 to the second object, I think this is the infinite for loop error, but I don't know how to solve it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think there is better way to remove the item from this collection

work with the object refrence to delete any of those clicked items \

```typescript
removePhase(id:number){ 
   // but becareful here we override the main list again then we add it to the data source  
    this.phase = this.phase.filter(item => item.id !== id)
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.phase);
    console.log(this.phase) // will have your items without the clicked one 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
removePhase(id:number){
    this.phaseRemove = [];
    console.log(this.phase) /*First log*/
    for(const element of this.phase) {
      if (element.id != id) {
        this.phaseRemove.push(element);
      }
    }
    for (let i=0 ; i< this.phaseRemove.length; i++){
      this.phaseRemove[i].id = i;
    }
    this.phase = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.phaseRemove));
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.phase);
    console.log(this.phase) /*Second log*/
}
```

The issue is caused because thereis a reference between this.phase and this.phaseRemove. They are a similar object which are pointing to one place inside the memory.

You should break their reference using the JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()). Then you will let them to be completely different objects.